# Registry editing using CMD , Path isn't added

Tags: batch-file, cmd, registry

lets start by giving you my code:

```
@echo off
echo.Add App Shortcut for use with
echo.Windows+R
echo.A.K.A Windows "RUN" Command
echo.===========================
color 0E
echo.Make Sure you do not run as admin
pause
cls
color 07
del tool.reg
cls
echo.Example: HxD
set /p key="Type the name of the app shortcut here: "
cls
echo.Example: F:\Tools\HxD
set /p appfolder="Type the folder of the app here: "
cls
echo.Example: F:\Tools\HxD\HxD.exe
set /p apppath="Type the path of the app here: "
cls
echo Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 >> tool.reg
echo [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths] >> tool.reg
echo "%key%"=Key >>tool.reg
echo [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\%key%] >> tool.reg
echo "Default"="%apppath%" >> tool.reg
echo "Path"="%appfolder%" >> tool.reg
pause
echo.Launching The Tool
start tool.reg
```

So what's the problem here is , the path is for example F:\Programs\HxD . whenever that path is entered , it detects the slash "\" and stops the command from being executed. is there a workaround on this? 
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you should use `reg add` you could get your current code to work by adding the following:

```
set appfolder=%appfolder:\=\\%
```

For each variable that you expect <kbd>\</kbd>.  This will replace each instance with `\\` to escape it.

Comment: Thanks works! But there's an issue , how can I modify the (Default) one? when I change (Default) it creates another one.
Edit: "" = Default , nevermind found it.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you use the `REG` command instead of trying to build up a registry file. For example, something like this:

```
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\%key%" /v "Default" /d "%apppath%"
```

Comment: ok so I did this , nothing happens after it says operation succesful